# Using VBA to copy data from one worksheet into another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a slight problem in Excel. I need to sync up the values in the curly braces `{}` found in column C and put them against the user id in column F. I would like this data to be copied across to a new worksheet in the same workbook. Any ideas how I could accomplish this? You don't have to provide any code but a nudge in the right direction would be great.

E.g. on the **Emails** sheet

[image]

becomes this on a new sheet

[image]

Comment: Where is your code? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @enderland Hi enderland, I'm quite new to VBA and was just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. I've been on SO for a while and know very well that it is far from a code writing service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone needs help, this is the solution:

```
Sub CopyConditional()
    Dim wshS As Worksheet
    Dim WhichName As String

    Set wshS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Emails")
    WhichName = "NewSheet"

    Const NameCol = "C"
    Const FirstRow = 1

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim SrcRow As Long
    Dim TrgRow As Long
    Dim wshT As Worksheet
    Dim cpt As String
    Dim user As String
    Dim computers() As String
    Dim computer As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wshT = Worksheets(WhichName)
    If wshT Is Nothing Then
        Set wshT = Worksheets.Add(After:=wshS)
        wshT.Name = WhichName
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wshT.Cells(1, NameCol).value = "" Then
        TrgRow = 1
    Else
        TrgRow = wshT.Cells(wshT.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If

    LastRow = wshS.Cells(wshS.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For SrcRow = FirstRow To LastRow
        cpt = wshS.Range("C" & SrcRow).value
        user = wshS.Range("F" & SrcRow).value

        If InStr(cpt, ":") Then
            cpt = Mid(cpt, InStr(1, cpt, ":") + 1, Len(cpt))
        End If

        If InStr(cpt, ";") Then
            computers = Split(cpt, ";")
            For i = 0 To UBound(computers)
                If computers(i) <> "" Then
                    wshT.Range("A" & TrgRow).value = user
                    wshT.Range("B" & TrgRow).value = Mid(Left(computers(i), Len(computers(i)) - 1), 2)
                    TrgRow = TrgRow + 1
                End If
            Next
        Else
            computer = cpt
            If computer <> "" Then
                wshT.Range("A" & TrgRow).value = user
                wshT.Range("B" & TrgRow).value = Mid(Left(computer, Len(computer) - 1), 2)
                TrgRow = TrgRow + 1
            End If
        End If

    Next SrcRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

You didn't ask a question. Basically what you would do is

```
loop through the values in column F
  for each value, get the value in column C
  loop through all braced values in column C
    let braceValue = parse column C searching for {value}
    create a row in new worksheet with column F value, braceValue
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've since updated the question